# bash: find the name of a file and assign to a variable

Tags: bash, scripting

In bash, I want to search a directory which contains a file that I'm expecting:

```
find . -name "myfile-*.war"
```

assign the name of this file to a variable, and then rename the file to newfile.war.

Comment: Is the file in the directory directly or in some sub-(sub-?)directory of it?

Comment: Is the assignment to a variable essential, or is it superfluous if the renaming gets done by other means? Are you sure that there will be only one file which matches your search parameter?

Comment: If there is only one file, and no subdirectories, why do you need `find`?

Comment: the assignment to a variable is not essential, but a nice to have.  I am not 100% sure there is only a single file that matches

Comment: I do not need to use find.

Comment: the file is in a subdirectory

Comment: And if there are multiple matches in one subdirectory, all but one of them should be deleted, because only one of them can be called `newfile.war`?

Comment: What do you do if more than one file matches?

Comment: if there is more than one match, error out

Comment: @tripleee either I will write a script to delete the file ahead of time, or the script can delete newfile.war as part of the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assign the file to a variable, just rename it with the `-execdir` option to `find`:

```
find . -name 'myfile-*.var' -execdir mv {} newfile.war \;
```

Comment: Perhaps mention that this will effectively remove files if there are  multiple matches in the same directory. They will all be renamed on top of each other, successively  replacing the previously renamed file.

Comment: Wouldn't this move the file to `find`'s working directory?

Comment: Good catch. I changed to `-execdir` so it runs the command inside the directory of the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure the find command will return exactly 1 file you can use this:

```
name=$(find . -name "myfile-*.war" )
```